# Как запустить ассемблер в Notepad++

Tags: ассемблер

(RU):Я скачал в NotePad++ плагин NppExec, проблема заключается в том что мне надо запустить ассемблер именно в NotePad++. Я порылся в просторах интернета, но при долгих поисках в итоге я нашел информацию о том что надо для этого даже скачивать плагин NppExec. Я не знаю как запустить asm в NotePad++.

вот собственно код ассемблера на всякий случай:

```
section .data
hello: db 'Hello Assembly',10
helloLen: equ $-hello

section .text
 global _start

_start:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,hello
    mov edx,helloLen

    int 80h

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h;
```

P.S (начал изучать ассемблер только что)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Конкретная проблема заключается в том что, как надо запускать ассемблер в Notepad++ ? Как? Как запустить ассемблер в Notepad++ ?

Comment: Notepad не предназначен для запуска ассемблера - это просто текстовый редактор. Если вы хотите собирать программы на ассемблере, то скачайте соответствующий компилятор. Тогда на выходе получите исполняемый файл *.exe. Советую FASM: https://flatassembler.net/download.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно ничего дополнительно устанавливать.

Тебе нужно написать BAT-файл в котором указать все параметры запуска, после чего ты сможешь запускать BAT-файл посредством меню RUN.

В BAT-файле тебе нужно будет указать все параметры сборки и прочие обязательные пункты. Как их указать это отдельный вопрос, хочешь узнать задавай его отдельно.